# Generate PDF on the server from Google Maps API?

Tags: pdf-generation, google-maps-api-3, kml

We have a hosted [web app](http://devresults.com) that uses the Google Maps API for various types of geographical reports, using a combination of the javascript API for adding markers and shapes, plus KML overlays for other layers.

There's some demand from customers for turning these into nice downloadable & printable PDF maps. I'm not sure where to begin with that. Any ideas?

Comment: You should begin at [Googlemaps legal notice](http://www.google.com/help/legalnotices_maps.html). Your idea would probably fall under 3.1(b) so you should first obtain a license at Tele Atlas.

Comment: Not a lawyer, but I think we're OK. My reading of the legal notice is that it's not OK to, say, make an atlas using their map data and then sell it for money. Obviously you're allowed to print a map from a browser, and I'd just like to do that with slightly higher quality.

Answer (score 4):

As Mark Storer pointed out, you can use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

If you have polylines or other stuff in your map you will likely need wkhtmltopdf to wait for all the pieces to be in place before generating the PDF.
This can be done with the latest version 0.10.0_rc2 and with the **--window-status** parameter (javascript in your target page will have to update the window.status variable once everything is ready).

Check out the manual [here](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html)

An example usage goes like this:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --page-size A4 --dpi 600 --window-status ready --print-media-type http://www.yoursite.com/target.html target.pdf
```

Cons: the whole process is a bit overkill in terms of resources, so if your webapp gets plenty of hits you may want to pay close attention to this aspect.

Comment: Not to others: if the wkhtmltopdf process encounters javascript errors it's possible it'll never fire the window.status change causing the process to hang indefinitely, which is bad.

Answer (score 2):

Once you work out all the legal details, I recommend looking at wkthmltopdf.  It will *accurately* evaluate the page's JavaScript, critical to any Google Map web page.

Answer (score -1):

You will need a Premier license with Google otherwise you will be breaking the Terms of Service

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any thoughts on the actual question I asked?

Comment: If you get a premier license then you will be able to use static maps for printing